# Is the hash necessary in svg font-face declarations?

Tags: css, svg, font-face

```
@font-face
  font-family: 'AllerRegular'
  src: url('/fonts/aller/aller_rg-webfont.eot')
  src: url('/fonts/aller/aller_rg-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('/fonts/aller/aller_rg-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('/fonts/aller/aller_rg-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('/fonts/aller/aller_rg-webfont.svg#AllerRegular') format('svg')
  font-weight: normal
  font-style: normal
```

In the example above, I'm adding an svg version of this font but I'm not sure the ID is correct. If there is only one font included in this SVG is it necessary to have the correct id?

Comment: Wouldn't trying with and without the hashtag answer that question?

Comment: Was thinking someone might now off-hand. I think these font files are only used for ipad/iphone and I'm not able to access this app currently on either device.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Yes, it is required. [This article](https://web.archive.org/web/20150102141618/http://www.fluorcow.com/embedding-fonts-on-a-website) says:

> In the CSS code above, you can actually see that the SVG version needs an extra info, its ID, after the hashtag (#) in the file name
> declaration. If you don’t fill it it’s not working, so you need to
> find this information opening the SVG file in a TXT document or
> notepad and look for the following line, near the top of page.

And [this one](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/download-embed-fonts-font-face/) says:

> With SVG fonts, they also need a #hashtag;

The hashtag is simply a pointer to the ID of the font defined inside the SVG. If you don't include it, the whole SVG file will be loaded, including SVG headers that prevent the font from being recognized.

Comment: finally someone explains this, +1

Comment: Say you have a path like 'fonts/thefont.svg#thefont' -- can you add a version GET variable, i.e., 'fonts/thefont.svg#thefont?v=3.2.1'? I ask because I couldn't get a SVG font to load in Chrome with the GET variable attached.

Comment: @aendrew You probably need to swap your URL parts around, cos everything after the hash is *not* sent to the server.  So try `thefont.svg?v=3.2.1#thefont`.  I haven't tested it, but it's more likely to work.

Comment: @Simon Hi mate, this doesn't work unfortunately. Modern browsers only require WOFF fonts thankfully - https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/26992/if-i-have-only-woff-and-eot-what-browsers-am-i-supporting-with-font-face